# Finding the smallest number in a list from a textfile: Python

Tags: python, list, min

In my code, I am trying to get a list of numbers from a text file and find the smallest two of them. How would i do this?

```
Myfile = open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt","r")

AScore = ()
BScore = ()
CScore = ()
DScore = ()
EScore = ()
FScore = ()

for line in Myfile:
    if "A" in line.split(',')[0]:
        AScore = line.split(',')[1]

for line in Myfile:
    if "B" in line.split(',')[0]:
        BScore = line.split(',')[1]

for line in Myfile:
    if "C" in line.split(',')[0]:
        CScore = line.split(',')[1]

for line in Myfile:
    if "D" in line.split(',')[0]:
        DScore = line.split(',')[1]

for line in Myfile:
    if "E" in line.split(',')[0]:
        EScore = line.split(',')[1]

for line in Myfile:
    if "F" in line.split(',')[0]:
        FScore = line.split(',')[1]


list1 = [AScore, BScore, CScore, DScore, EScore, FScore]

int(list1)
smallest = min(list1)
print(smallest)

Myfile.close()
```

The error that keeps coming up is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    EliminateR1()
  File "D:\NEA Real\Test3.py", line 39, in EliminateR1
    int(list1)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: How does your .txt file look like?

Comment: A, 29 (\n) B, 14 (\n) C, 32 (\n) D, 18 (\n) E, 11 (\n) F, 35 (Each on a new line)

Comment: I'm guessing the whole point is to give the letters (as well as the value?) for the two smallest values or you could just ignore them?

Comment: I need to find the two lowest scores,  and then save the four (that aren't the two lowest) to a new text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, assuming your data looks something like this. If you want the minimum, you can use `min`. If you want the two smallest values, you can `sort` the list and pick the 2 first ones:

```
txt = """A,1
B,3
F,5
D,4
C,2"""

values = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in txt.splitlines()]
print(values)
# [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
print(min(values))
# 1
print(sorted(values))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sorted(values)[:2])
# [1, 2]
```

If you read from a file, you can use :

```
with open("RoundOneTotalScores.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
values = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in lines]
print(values)
# [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
print(min(values))
# 1
print(sorted(values))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sorted(values)[:2])
# [1, 2]
print(sorted(values)[2:])
# [3, 4, 5]
```

Note that collections such as list, dict and sets are defined so that you don't need to define `AScore`, `BScore`, ...

Comment: Thank you Eric Duminil but will that work under the basis that: The scores in the textfile will be changing

Comment: That is absolutely amazing. Thank you. Now when it prints the two lowest values, how can I separate them so that I can use them separately?

Comment: Just a small suggestion: You could leave the `with` block after receiving the data in its first line. No need to keep the file open longer.